# How to use stanford parser to get line-by-line parsed file

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

If I have a file like test.txt, including each sentences per line, how can I obtain a output file in the following format:
"
`( ( ( Effective) ( but)) ( ( too-tepid) ( biopic))) \n
( ( ( If) ( ( you) ( ( sometimes) ( ( like) ( ( to) ( ( ( go) ( ( to) ( ( the) ( movies)))) ( ( to) ( ( have) ( fun))))))))) ( ( ,) ( ( Wasabi) ( ( ( is) ( ( a) ( ( good) ( ( place) ( ( to) ( start)))))) ( .))))) \n`
"
 Thanks you!

Comment: If you want a `tl;dr` answer, see https://github.com/alvations/nltk_cli

Answer (score 0):

Use the java api, which gives you flexibility towards what you are doing. Also have a look at the example, and the last line command on this page:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Comment: Would you please be a little more specific?